# How to fine-tune the position of a point in SketchUp LayOut?

Tags: layout, sketchup

I created multiple curves for doing drawing with picture match (Btw, Use LayOut do picture match is much easier than SketchUp).

I've read [this help page](https://help.sketchup.com/en/article/3000205), but they didn’t say how to fine-tune a axis of the curve.
It always sticks to grid or some alignment auxiliary line, I cannot do my work with this.

Comment: After selecting the point, can you enter new coordinates of the point in the bottom (measurement) bar much like when you want to enter the dimensions of a shape?

Comment: may I suggest making an [edit] to include those examples?  Might get a quicker and better answer if you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original post:
https://forums.sketchup.com/t/can-anybody-help-me-with-this-just-a-question-how-to-fine-tune-the-position-of-a-point-in-layout/51923/6

Solution: Go to the Arrange menu and turn off Object Snap and Grid Snap.

Comment: If you answered your own question please mark it as the accepted answer.